# How do I determine order of growth of periodic function? (sin)

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am self-reading Levin's book, on Entire functions.
There is a task that needs to be verified by the reader, and I cannot reproduce it.
It states:

"Verify that $sin(Az)$ is of order $p = 1$ and type $\sigma = |A|$"

My attempt was the following:
$sin (Az)$ is a function:

1. periodic
2. limited by growth, with a maximum result value equal to 1.

Thus,
$$
p = \left[ \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{log(log(M_f(r)))}{log(r)} \right]
$$

As $ log(log(M_f(r)))$ is limited, as sinus is limited, thus we are getting

$$
p = \left[ \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{limited}{log(r)} \right]
$$
and $log(r)$ is -> to $\infty$ as $r\to\infty$
Thus $p = 0$, and

$$
\sigma = \left[ \limsup_{r\to\infty} \frac{log(M_f(r))}{r^p} \right]
$$

Where $M_f(r) = 1$(maximum value of sinus), $log(1) = 0$ which results in
$$
\sigma = \frac{0}{\infty} = 0
$$

Where had I taken it wrong? Should I somehow try to use "wonderful limit"?
What is general rule to estimate growth of periodic functions?

By the way, I was thinking of converting the sin into the Taylor series, but in this case, I feel the temptation of putting to $p = \infty$, which nonetheless verifies anything.

Comment: just look at $\sin iAx$ for real $x$ which is essentially a hyperbolic sine so grows like an exponential

Comment: Continuous and periodic implies bounded on the real line, but does not imply bounded on the complex plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

1. It is required to rewrite $sin(z)$, like that: $sin(z) = \frac{ e^{iz} - e^{-iz} }{2i}$
2. I have found the [complete solution](https://scholarworks.umt.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=9103&context=etd):

P.S. Also, worth checking out this [question & accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274704/order-of-growth-of-the-entire-function-sin-sqrtz-sqrtz?rq=1)